# Select Folder Path with savefileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to using a dialog window to get the folder path without name file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

```
// Bring up a dialog to chose a folder path in which to open or save a file.
private void folderMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    // Show the FolderBrowserDialog.
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if( result == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        string folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        ... //Do your work here!
    }
}
```

Comment: @Luca's: Did you check the link? There's an quite extensive example.

Comment: too long! in that example tells how to open a rtf file not find out how to select a folder

Answer (score 62):

Though an old question,

I didn't like that ugly`FolderBrowserDialog`, so here's a trick that worked for me, it uses the `SaveFileDialog`

```
// Prepare a dummy string, thos would appear in the dialog
string dummyFileName = "Save Here";

SaveFileDialog sf = new SaveFileDialog();
// Feed the dummy name to the save dialog
sf.FileName = dummyFileName;

if(sf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // Now here's our save folder
    string savePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(sf.FileName);
   // Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Adding dialog.CheckFileExists = false; will mean the use can browse around folders without selecting a file, the dummy will be accepted.

Comment: Which is false by default for `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: The draw back is that If the file name is blank the user can't click ok. :(

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been looking for this solution for quite a long time.

Comment: I've also added `sf.Filter = "Directory | directory";` to hide all the files to the user.